# Does renderDT have a bug when rendering datatable %>% formatStyle?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I am trying to display a data table using shiny dashboard and DT formatStyle and am getting an error: invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? The formatStyle modifications to iris are straight out of the DT package manual and run properly if I don't renderDT the instructions. However when I do try to render, I get the above error.

```
   ui =  fluidPage(DTOutput("tableX"))

server = function(input, output, session) {
   output$tableX = renderDT(iris,        
      datatable(iris) %>% 
          formatStyle(columns ='Sepal.Length',
              fontWeight = styleInterval(5, c('bold', 'weight')))%>%
          formatStyle('Sepal.Width',
              color = styleInterval(3.4, c('red', 'white')),
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(3.4, c('yellow', 'gray'))
      )
    )
} 

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: `renderDT(iris, datatable(iris)`? What's that? Remove `iris,`.

Comment: No. I'm only using "renderDT(iris, ..." as an example that breaks the renderDT function. I ran into the problem when I was trying to renderDT a data table that I was using and wanted to add color to with the " %>%   formatStyle" . I just used the iris example because it seemed to me to be a clear indication of a problem I was not going to be able to resolve without expert help. I understand that there may not be a viable, robust fix, but I would be happy with a workaround....I apologize for taking so long to realize that you had commented and in responding. I'm new to this.

Comment: There's no bug. Your code `renderDT(iris, datatable(iris)...` makes no sense. Just do `renderDT(datatable(iris)`.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. How do I change colors of columns and also renderDT in order to display the table? I thought that I had to make a style change before doing the render. The iris example I showed came out of The Package 'DT' manual,January 30, 2018, page 12, the last example, "# apply CSS styles to columns". It works perfectly, and, as you point out, so long as I do not render DT the table. I want to render the data table in order display the table.  Is there some other way to open a modal a display the table?